# save application configurations

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

Is there a way to save application configurations and settings that user have customized in a way like we use the `app.config` file?
the `app.config` file is read-only so I cannot add keys or edit values in it.

I want something easy to use that have add or edit keys and values just like `app.config`.
users customize their settings in visual forms and then the program should store it.

Comment: Are you talking about the user manually editing the file, or using settings marked as within the User scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal `app.config` is only read-only to the normal user, but a shadow is written to the user's data folders when you save a User setting.

But you may have to expand on "Add keys".

Comment: I want a file for example option.config with features to add and remove and edit keys easily.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ConfigurationManager` in `System.Configuration namespace`

Answer (score 0):

Isolated storage can be used for this purpose:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I would also suggest not to modify app.config from application by any mean. It is better to use app.config configuration as default configuration and store any changes within Isolated Storage. On application startup, give preference to isolated storage configration, and if not found then read it from app.config. Hope this will help.

Comment: it is for silverlight i think!

Comment: Isolated storage is supported on all platforms, so this implementation can be used in your senario as well.